# ruby native extension: undefined symbol

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension, extconf.rb, ruby-native-extensions

I'm attempting to create a ruby native extension, but when I run `rake` which uses `ext/example_project/extconf.rb` to build my project and run my tests under `test/`, I get the following error when the tests are run:

```
./home/jbuesking/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: 
/home/jbuesking/repositories/example_project/lib/example_project/example_project.so: undefined symbol: some_function
```

I'm pretty sure my files are not being linked correctly and that I need to alter my `extconf.rb` and/or `Rakefile` in some way, but I'm not sure how.

I've created a simple repository that demonstrates the issue [over on GitHub](https://github.com/JesseBuesking/example_project). It'll fail with the same error if you clone it and run `rake` from the projects root.

Some additional information:

- I used the ruby gem `hoe` to create the project via `sow example_project`
- The failing function is attempting to call a function defined in the subdirectory `ext/example_project/c_example_project`. My actual project uses a git submodule from the `ext/example_project` directory, which in turn sets up the submodule as a subdirectory. The submodule is a c project with a flattened structure (all files in the root directory). **Note**: That wording may be confusing, but the key point is that there's a nested c project defined at `ext/example_project/c_example_project` which has methods I'm trying to call.

Let me know if any clarification is needed, and I'll do my best to provide it.

Comment: Just a follow up, if there's something better than `hoe` for doing this, please let me know. I was [using a tutorial](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/12/18/writing-ruby-c-extensions-part-1.html) as a launchpoint, but it's 7 years old so maybe something better has come along since then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there are some interesting issues you have here. By default, mkmf doesn't actually support specifying multiple directories for building sources.

There is a workaround, as seen here (Takehiro Kubo's comment about setting objs):

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4224640

Basically, you construct the `$objs` global in your `extconf.rb` file yourself.

Using your github code, here's what I added to the extconf.rb and got to work

**extconf.rb**

```
globs = [".", "c_example_project"].map do |directory|
  File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), directory)
end.join(",")

$objs = Dir.glob("{#{globs}}/*.c").map do |file|
  File.join(File.dirname(file), "#{File.basename(file, ".c")}.o")
end
```

Notice I'm actually constructing an absolute path to each of the c sources, for some reason rake-compiler was freaking out if we were just globbing with `{.,c_example_project}/*.c`, presumably since it's running the extconf.rb file from another directory.

In addition, your tests/c extensions have a few errors in them. Making the following change in `example_project.c` fixes the test failure:

```
 static VALUE example_project_c_code_function()
 {
-    return some_function();
+    VALUE _string = rb_str_new2(some_function());
+    int _enc = rb_enc_find_index("UTF-8");
+    rb_enc_associate_index(_string, _enc);
+    return _string;
 }
```

**Explanation**

Basically even though you're checking the c_example_project.h header in your extconf.rb, you're not actually generating the object file where `some_function` is defined. So, when linking the final dynamic library that ruby loads up, there's no definition for `some_function` and you get your error.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, I thought the issue was that the file's weren't being compiled and linked correctly, I just had no idea how to make that work. Thank you for figuring out what needed to be done!

Comment: Truly great. Definitely useful information. Though, I think the path generated in the sample code is not absolute paths, $objs is an Enumerator, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with building native extensions, but from `mkmf` source code it looks like you can only specify one source directory. I moved both files from `c_example_project` to the parent directory and everything was linked properly. I think that is how you should do it. All common gems (like pg, nokogiri etc) have such code structure, all *.c and *.h files are in one directory.

You can always create `Makefile` yourself, but that would require too much work to maintain.

PS. Your project compiled successfully, but you there is segmentation fault, because you should return proper ruby string object in `some_function` and not pointer to a string.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that did not involve moving the files up a directory, as that means I can no longer use the git submodule and instead have to rely on copying files manually... if no one else leaves a better answer I'll accept yours, although I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

photoionized has a great answer, but $obj can be an array instead of an Enumerator.It seems to be okay to simply use an absolute path.

```rb
$objs = Dir.glob([".c", "libfoobar/*.c"], base: __dir__)
           .map { |f| File.expand_path(f, __dir__) }
           .map { |f| f.sub(/\.c$/, ".o") }
```